# Python equivalent for ordertrack function in matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I'm looking for a Python (numpy/scipy) equivalent of the ordertrack function in matlab. With this functionality i want to be able to perform order-tracking analysis with vibration measurements on slow rotating machinery. I searched extensively for examples on Google/Stackexchange, but I could not find anything. Although i found enough examples with regular FFT spectra analysis.

More information on the function can be found here: https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/ordertrack.htm

Comment: Please explain the downvoting or possible improvements to the question

Comment: This question probably belongs to a different site: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/. Is it possible to move the entire question?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`vibration-toolbox`](http://vibrationtoolbox.github.io/vibration_toolbox/index.html) package. More precise, the class [`vibration-toolbox.vibesystem.VibeSystem`](http://vibrationtoolbox.github.io/vibration_toolbox/reference/vibe_system.html#vibration-systems-vibesystem).

It is set up a little bit differently than the python function, but such an instance

```
from vibration-toolbox.vibesystem import VibeSystem
sys = VibeSystem(M=your_signal_mass, C=your_signal_damping, K=your_signal_stiffness)
```

is basically a vibration signal instance with a specific mass, damping and stiffness, which would correspond to the signal `x` in MATLABs `ordertrack` function.

The method [`VibeSystem.freq_response`](http://vibrationtoolbox.github.io/vibration_toolbox/reference/vibe_system.html#vibration_toolbox.vibesystem.VibeSystem.freq_response) would then be able to calcuate the magnitudes you want.

```
omega, magdb, phase = sys.freq_response(omega=your_signal_rpm, modes=your_signal_orderlist)
```

`magdb` should then contain the magnitudes you are looking for.

Unfortunately, I do not have the Signal Processing Toolbox in MATLAB, so I cannot compare the code and show an example.

Comment: I think this might be a bit different, than what i'm looking for. I do not know beforehand what the exact characteristics (i.e. Mass, stiffness or damping matrix) are of the system what is being measured.